# How do I dockerize an application which spawns child processes?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, architecture

I have an application (lets call it, endpoint service) which spawns a child process upon getting an API request. The child processes needs to communicate with outside world over a TCP connection. How do I containerize it? Is it okay to have one docker container for the endpoint service, and spawn the child processes in the same container. They can use the same base image (node/alpine).

Comment: You shouldn't need to do anything special; this would all run in a single container.  The only important consideration is that the main application becomes the init process inside the container, so if your children spawn children but then exit your process could wind up being the parent of processes it didn't create itself.

Comment: You used `kubernetes` tag, are you using it any way? Could you paste an example code of your app and Dockerfile (if you have any)? Please make your [issue reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Sorry @MikolajS, we are still in the designing phase so no code yet. Although I am using kubernetes, it does not directly pertain to this question, I shall remove it.

Comment: Thankyou @DavidMaze for your inputs.